Debugging Ionic and Angular 18 with Capacitor in Android device using Xamarin's AVD
I have been working on debugging a webpage built on Ionic and Angular with Capacitor. Debugging in Android device requires me to download and install Android Studio to run the AVD.
Are there any way to launch the AVD that comes with Xamarin's cross-platform development?
Thank you
I have tried to look into the web and all of them seemed to be referring to installing the AVD from Android Studio. Haven't really found any clue to debug with Xamarin's installed AVD.
